# Nuxtjs + youtube data api

Tags: vue.js, google-api, youtube-data-api, nuxt.js

Want to use youtube data api in my Nuxt app

Question:
in google docs in js example gapi is used (*https://apis.google.com/js/api.js*)

what's the purpose of this lib if I can simply use requests like:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&chart=mostPopular&key=*MyAPIKey*

as I've noticed, in there example with gapi (*https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list*) there is no API Key, but ClientId

and in simple get request above there is no ClientId but simply API Key

So,
1. why to use gapi? is it better and more correct than using simple get requests like example above?
2. why in one case they use ClientId and in another it's enough to send API key? is the first approach is more safe or what?
3. what's the best use of Youtube Data API in Nuxt? have to use gapi or send simple get requests with API key?